# Call contract method via metamask without web3

Tags: web3js, metamask

https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/reference/json-rpc-api/

window.web3 is no longer injected by metamask, instead it is window.ethereum, but loads of methods are missing. It used to be very simple, just:

```
contract = new window.web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
...
const a = await contract.methods.testCall().call();
```

I don't understand how to do this now, there is no Contract method. There is a request({"method": "eth_call"...) but I don't understand how to use it.

It seems like they took something very simple that was working and broke it.

Comment: You can always embed your own copy of web3 in your page, and initialize it to use window.ethereum as rpc provider.